# Compojure/Noir using Spring Security for auth & auth?

Tags: clojure, spring-security

Caveat: I'm coming from a PHP background, with a few Java/Tomcat skills that are rusty and out-of-date.

I've been using Sandbar with Compojure to secure my web app, but I hear it's relatively simple to use Spring Security to handle basic user authentication and role-based access restrictions. I've been through the Spring Security tutorials, but I can't quite make the translation to Clojure code. Does anyone have a sample web app or even just a few pointers that would show me how to drop in Spring Security for my auth & auth? Links to existing docs are welcome too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow [this example](http://smuglispmeanie.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-spring-security-with-ring-jetty.html) which integrates Spring and Spring Security into a Compojure application running on Jetty.  All the source code for a working example can be found on [github](https://github.com/lispnik/ring-spring-security).

Comment: Awesome, I don't think I would have come up with that on my own, thanks much!